API is working from other domains but when I tried to call API from my subdomain it gives error

Access to XMLHttpRequest at ... has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Heders in preflight response.


API is working from other domains but when I tried to call API from my subdomain it gives this error.
I tried with some headers in my code but API returns CORS error.
Code of my request.php page
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, post, get');
header('Content-type: application/json');

$data = [ 'msisdn' => '1111', 'result' => 'success', 'message' => 'hi'  ];

echo $a=json_encode( $data ); 


Did you understand the error message? Your client side code is sending a header which isn't permitted by the server in that pre-flight scenario. So either set the header as allowed, or don't send it. Note that it's the pre-flight request it complained about, so it's possible it's not php which handles that, but your webserver - depends a bit on your configuration

"Request header field content-type is not allowed" is what the error message is telling you. Have you tried removing it?

@ADyson I have already kept Headers in my php code & client is using flutter

Not sure what you're trying to tell me? Your php code doesn't set the allowed-headers CORS setting. Your request is sending a header which isn't allowed by default. That's what the error is about. Have you done any research yet? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers

@ADyson Yes, have done research & tried many things to resolve the issue. In the image, first /request API is handled by me & I have allowed headers. Even client getting reach to our API but they don't see any response.  but in my database we can see entry when client send request.

Content-Type is a CORS-safelisted request header - but only if the value is one of either application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain. If your clients are sending something else - then you need to allow for that, by adding an Access-Control-Allow-Headers that allows Content-Type.

tried many things...such as? We've told you now what the options for a solution are...not sure there are many things it would make sense to try outside of those. What exactly have you attempted?

@CBroe Close, but the allowed values extend beyond the three you listed, and missing this subtlety can open security holes.

I have found the resolution.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        // allow all origins
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}
    
// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
    {// may also be using PUT, PATCH, HEAD etc
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         
    }
    
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
    {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
    }
    
}

